Increase padding after a matrix
I find that the padding after a matrix in an equation is to small and therefore want to increase it. Is there a way I can globally change the padding at the bottom of a matrix to a higher value. The padding should also be applied when the matrix is part of another equation like \frac. I want to achieve a similar effect like adding a \vspace{1mm} after a matrix. So this:
\begin{gather*}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}

Should look something like this:
\begin{gather*}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
\vspace{2mm}\\
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
\vspace{2mm}
\end{gather*}


Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

Claims such as "[something] is too small" are quite vague and not actionable. Please edit your posting to provide a mininal compilable sample document that generates the problem you wish to fix.

I don't think a more detail is needed here. I don't know what the default padding is, I just want to increase it. But ok, added code blocks

Do you want to also increase spacing after a row without a matrix?  Or should that stay the same?

@Teepeemm If there isn't another option I guess I will be using the answer from @Mico but while this works 90% of the time when using matrix for example in a \frac the padding is gone

I don't think you want additional space after the gather* display. Adding vertical space in between the rows is easy.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[92][1-5]
\begin{gather*}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}\\[1ex]
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}
\lipsum[93][1-4]

\end{document}



I would like a way too increase the padding automatically, I don't want to change padding everywhere I use a matrix.

@LeoCodes Sorry, but this is essentially impossible as it highly depends on the context.

Isn't there any way to insert a \vspace{2mm} after each line that contains some sort of matrix?

The multi-row display-math environments of the amsmath package, including the gather* environment, insert vertical whitespace in the amount of \jot between rows; the default value of \jot is 3pt. If you want to increase this value by 2mm (which works out to about 5.69pt, since 1mm = approx. 2.845pt), you should execute
\addtolength{\jot}{2mm}

after loading the amsmath package.
The following screenshot contrasts the default spacing on the left against the additional (automated) spacing on the right. For the sake of the example, the value of \jot isn't increased until the second minipage starts. In general, though, you should probably change \jot in the preamble.

I've assumed implicitly that if the linespacing should be increased after a row that contains an xmatrix environment, this should hold for all other interior rows of a given amsmath multi-row display environment.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.333\textwidth}
\the\jot % show the default value
\hrule % illustrate start of 'gather*' env.
\begin{gather*}
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}
\hrule % illustrate end of 'gather*' env.
\end{minipage}
\quad % insert some horizontal whitespace
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.333\textwidth}
\addtolength{\jot}{2mm} \the\jot % show the new value
\hrule % illustrate start of 'gather*' env.
\begin{gather*}
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}
\hrule % illustrate end of 'gather*' env.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}


Thx this works most of the time, but when for example using a matrix in a \frac the line spacing logically isn't helping there

@Libadoxon - I don't believe you mentioned anything about matrix environments possibly occurring inside \frac expressions in your query. If that's one of your use cases, please edit your query to clarify what these use cases may be.
